# CodeBuild failing when running an image from ECR with exit status 1

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I am trying to pull an image from ECR and run it on ECS as containers. I am getting an 'exit status 1' while trying to build the image, this is my buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
      - aws --version
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 677630154057.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
      - REPOSITORY_URI=677630154057.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/partnersite
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - echo Writing image definitions file...
      - printf '[{"name":"partner-site","imageUri":"%s"}]' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imagedefinitions.json
artifacts:
    files: imagedefinitions.json
```

Here is my logs file:

```
[Container] 2021/10/18 17:22:01 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .. Reason: exit status 1
[Container] 2021/10/18 17:22:01 Entering phase POST_BUILD
[Container] 2021/10/18 17:22:01 Running command echo Build completed on `date`
Build completed on Mon Oct 18 17:22:01 UTC 2021

[Container] 2021/10/18 17:22:01 Running command echo Pushing the Docker images...
Pushing the Docker images...

[Container] 2021/10/18 17:22:01 Running command docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

[Container] 2021/10/18 17:22:01 Command did not exit successfully docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest exit status 1
[Container] 2021/10/18 17:22:01 Phase complete: POST_BUILD State: FAILED
[Container] 2021/10/18 17:22:01 Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest. Reason: exit status 1
```

Not sure what's causing the issue it runs alright on my local machine and EC2 instance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho4Bu.png) Would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: Are you running ECS in Fargate or EC2? The recommended method is to use EC2 for debugging so that you can log in to EC2 and see what is happening. What is the AMI you are using? You should be using from here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-optimized_AMI.html. Also, you need to check if `Priviledged` is checked.

Comment: I am using Fargate as of now, I can still access the logs.

Comment: Where do I get the privilege checkbox ?

Comment: `Privilege` box is only available for EC2 and not for Fargate or Windows

Comment: ohh okay, any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CodeBuild you need to make sure your environment has the "privileged" flag set: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these commands to the install phase of your build spec:

```
install:
    commands:
      - nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --storage-driver=overlay2 &
      - timeout 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"
```

Referenced from:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-docker-custom-image.html

You might also need to add:

```
VOLUME /var/lib/docker
```

to your Dockerfile and build a new image.